# Find out if checkbox is checked using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've read lots of other posts on SO from people with the same problem, everything I have tried so far has not worked.

I have HTML like so:

```
<ul>
  <li class="templateList">
    <input id="ctl00_MainContent_newCollection_wzd_lstSiteTypes_ctr10_chkSite" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="ctl00$MainContent$newCollection$wzd$SiteTypes$ctrl0$chkSite">
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
     ...
  </li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery I need to find all the checkboxes in the UL that are checked, then add a CSS class to the LI parent element called "selected".  This is what I have so far:

```
    $(".templateList input:checkbox").each(function () {
        var chk = $(this);
        alert($(chk).attr("checked"));
        if (chk.attr("checked")) {
            ... do something ...
        }
    });
```

The alert satement is for debug - it always says "undefined".

This is so simple but is driving me nuts!

Comment: Use the [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector

Comment: I recommend using `chk.is(':checked')` instead of `chk.attr("checked")`.

Answer (score 2):

You can save some time and variable assignments by just using `this`

```
$(".templateList input:checkbox").each(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        ... do something ...
    }
});
```

Comment: in fact best solution here

Answer (score 1):

Use [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to check whether the matched element satisfies the given selector and [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector to check whether the checkbox is checked.

```
$(".templateList input:checkbox").each(function () {
    var chk = $(this);
    if (chk.is("checked")) {
        ... do something ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use is() function with ":checked", like that:

```
$(chk).is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.prop()`:

```
$(".templateList input:checkbox").each(function () {
        var chk = $(this);
        alert($(chk).prop("checked"));
        if (chk.prop("checked")) {
            ... do something ...
        }
    });
```

Or shorthand:

```
$(".templateList input:checkbox").each(function () {
            var chk = $(this);            
            if (chk.is(":checked")) {
                ... do something ...
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".templateList input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){...})
```

Answer (score 0):

How about 'input:checkbox[checked]'? It will return what you need...